# Xamarin.Forms not recognizing SafeAreaInsets *at all*

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Running Visual Studio for Mac with Forms version 3.1.0.637273.

The documentation says to do this in the code-behind:

```
using Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;

 ...

On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOS>().SetUseSafeArea(true);
```

Or this in the Xaml:

```
xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core" 
ios:Page.UseSafeArea="true"
```

I've done both, and both give the same error:

```
Error CS1061: 'IPlatformElementConfiguration<iOS, Page>' does not contain a definition for 'SetUseSafeArea'
```

I get no error from just doing this:

```
On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOS>();
```

Which does me *no good*, but at least it proves that I'm accessing the `PlatformConfiguration.iOS` stuff without an error.

Why isn't my code recognizing anything having to do with SafeArea stuff at all?

Comment: What version of Xamarin.Forms are you using?

Comment: 2.4.0... trying to update to 3.1 now...

Comment: okay now on 3.1.0.637273, same error message

Comment: okay now it's working--updated and cleaned and quit and restarted and now it's working...